# Pick transistor to drive a coil from Attiny85 with 2.5 (+/-500) kHz signal (with screenshots)

Tags: transistors, frequency, npn, coil, switching

I have a small issue here.

I am trying to drive a coil from an AtTiny85. I am sending an output signal to a transistor and the transistor will then connect to a coil.

I know that I am sending the proper signal to the transistor, but this is not passing it properly to the coil. I am getting an output with noise and it is definitely not a square wave.

Am I missing a Diode? Did I pick a wrong transistor ? Do I have a wrong resistor value?

I am attaching the pictures of the circuit,data sheet and of the oscilloscope.

The transistor picked is an MMBT3904

[image: Schematic]

The signal that is connected to the base is the 2.5 kHz signal coming from the ATtiny that passes trough the 1k resistor.

[image: npn chart]

These are the properties of the transistor.

Do any of you have any ideas or suggestions?

I am adding the pictures of the oscilloscope

[image]

The code intends to change the frequency, and it is actually doing it, but not as intended.

[image]

[image]

I have also changed the BJT for a Mosfet, it did not work. I keep getting the same results.

Comment: Do you have any oscilloscope screenshots? What about using proper symbols for your schematic?

Comment: What's Vcc, what is the DC resistance and the inductance of your coil?

Comment: "_... with 2.5 (+/-500) kHz signal._" Do you mean 2.5 (±0.5) kHz?

Comment: in other question: How much current do you *expect* to flow through the coil?

Comment: "Am I missing a Diode" - **yes**

Comment: my Vcc is 5V, I am expecting 20 mA to pass in the coil. Yes I mean 0.5 kHz (500 Hz) so it will go up and down 2 kHz to 3 Khz

Comment: @Bart I have provided the screenshots

Comment: @Gioben: Fix the title then. ;^)

Comment: What's the coil for?

Comment: @jonk I want the coil to produce a magnetic field, but it has to be at a 2.5 kHz signal

Comment: All coils, given energy to store, produce a magnetic field. So that says nothing to me except what I already knew before. What is the _purpose_ here? What _function_ is being served by including it, at all?

Comment: @jonk It is for a personal experiment, which I need the coil to be driven at that frequency.

Comment: @gioben: What's the inductance? (I gather Vcc = 5V.) Or are you doing something here to measure the inductance?

Comment: Inductance = "definitely not a square wave" - Not much to add to that.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting an output with noise and it is definitely not a square
>   wave.

This is what I'd expect to see: -

So, start at the beginning with the transistor deactivated.

You then push current into the base from your MCU and pretty immediately the collector voltage falls to a few tens of milli volts above 0V. Within microseconds, this low voltage starts rising towards a couple of hundred milli volts (as one would expect given that the inductor current is rising from zero amps and the transistor's job is becoming more difficult).

Then you switch off the base and the collector voltage rises to (possibly) a few hundred volts except maybe the transistor breaks-down because the back emf (due to open circuiting the inductor). It might damage the transistor but you might get away with it due to a certain amount of current limiting from R4 and parasitic capacitance.

This high positive voltage surge might last hundreds of micro seconds then all the inductor's stored energy is gone and the collector will drop (whilst possibly oscillating/ringing a bit) back at Vcc (providing it didn't get damaged too much).

Then the process repeats.

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: i just want the coil to be driven at the oscillating 2.5 kHz signal. I would have to change my diagram or the transistor ?

Comment: I have provided the screenshots.

Comment: What is the coil for? How is it that you _know_ the current is supposed to be 20mA? Do you have a datasheet or part number for whatever device you are using that possesses the coil?

Comment: @jonk I need it to be 20mA there is no device that possesses the coil, it is just a bare coil, I am using it for its magnetic field

Comment: @gioben: then what is the inductance? and how do you _know_ by design that the current is 20mA? (Current is a function of time [among other things] with coils.) Is it just the resistor?

Comment: Never mind about the current. You know because of the resistor. Looks tentatively to me as though you are playing with the idea of measuring inductance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44005/discussion-between-gioben-and-jonk).

Comment: I can't do the chat thing but can you precisely state what you want to heppen or basically what you are trying to achieve? Your waveform shape roughly matches what your circuit would give but you are being unclear about what you want the current in the coil to be.

Comment: @Andyaka I want the current in my coil to be 20mA but more important than the current, I want the frequency of the coil to be the 2.5 kHz, this frequency will be oscillating +/- 500 Hz so it is going up and down 2000 Hz to 3000 Hz

Comment: If you are driving the coil with a square wave the current will be a triangle wave so you are either misled about what you want or you need a different circuit.